# Hand-crafted WSDL from XSD fails in CXF: the namespace on the "QueryResponse" element, is not a valid SOAP version

Tags: soap, xsd, wsdl, cxf

I have a web service that follows some of the semantics of a SOAP service, but they don't provide a WSDL for said service.  Instead, they provide an XSD, by which I'm reverse-engineering a WSDL out of.  Things seemed to be going well, even so far as to be able to

1. create a WSDL
2. Import the XSD as part of the WSDL using the `xsd:import` tag
3. Create Java wrappers with CXF
4. Call the service.

Now, what I get when I call the service is an exception:

```
INFO: Creating Service {http://service.something.net/xml}QueryService from WSDL: file:/C:/mydocs/Work/project/my-service.wsdl
Aug 09, 2011 1:22:34 PM org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain doDefaultLogging
WARNING: Interceptor for {http://service.something.net/xml}QueryService#{http://servicesomething..../xml}QueryRequest has thrown exception, unwinding now
org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.SoapFault: "http://service.something.net/xml", the namespace on the "QueryResponse" element, is not a valid SOAP version.
```

The WSDL can be found [in this gist](https://gist.github.com/1134842), and the XSD is something I got from the vendor.

**What does the error mean?  What might I have done wrong in my `.wsdl` file generation?**

### Edit 1

I have manually tested the service from the vendor service, and the response seems okay to me:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Envelope xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <Body>
        <QueryResponse xmlns="http://service.something.net/xml">
        ....
        </QueryResponse>
    </Body>
</Envelope>
```

Unless I'm missing something, there should not be any reason why CXF even wants the `QueryResponse` to be a SOAP element, since it's namespace isn't SOAP but `http://service.something.net/xml`.

Answer (score 1):

Where you are importing your XSD:

```
<wsdl:types>
    <xsd:schema targetNamespace="http://service.something.net/xml">
        <xsd:include schemaLocation="My-XSD.xsd" />
    </xsd:schema>
    <xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
        <xsd:import namespace="http://service.something.net/xml"
            schemaLocation="My-XSD.xsd">
        </xsd:import>
    </xsd:schema>
</wsdl:types>
```

try this instead:

```
<wsdl:types>
    <xs:schema targetNamespace="http://service.something.net/xml" 
               elementFormDefault="qualified">
        <xs:import schemaLocation="My-XSD.xsd"/>
    </xs:schema>
</wsdl:types>
```

Basically you shouldn't need the include, just the import. Also you want to specify fully qualified element form.

Hope this works.

Comment: While that does simplify the .wsdl, I get the same error.  In fact, if I remove the `namespace` attribute on the `xsd:import`, I get an error "An imported schema was announced to have the namespace , but has
the namespace `http://service.something.net/xml`", so that part I had to put back in.

Comment: Hmm. Out of interest, what is the reason for xmlns="default namespace" in the "query_response" wsdl:part?

Comment: Nothing in particular.  I'm fumbling along with IDE help generating the WSDL, so it could possibly be an errant mistake.

Comment: I would remove it. Your error seems to be related to QueryResponse.

Comment: It's been removed, and I've updated the wsdl a touch.  Same exceptions throughout, however...